# Restrict Access to other JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog

How do i restrict access to other JFrame?

if I open my main frame and when click the button to display other jframe, the user should not be able to go back to the main frame.

how do I do that?

Comment: Its you who decide if he should go back to the frame.Don't let him go!

Comment: please try to improve your question and post the code so that others could figure out what you are up to and what progress have you already made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method...

```
this.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

> if i open my main frame and click the add button,

When you click the button you display a modal JDialog. Then until the user closes the dialog they won't be able to access the main frame.

Comment: if use the jdialog, dose not display on taskbar

Comment: @user986566: why does that matter? And you should accept some of the answers given to you in previous threads, lest folks not want to help you any more.

Comment: Also, what is the use of an extra icon on the task-bar, when the user cannot click it to go back to the other frame?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me but as per my understanding I believe You want to open a dialog on button click but when you click the button a new JFrame is displayed and it becomes impossible for you to get back to the original frame.

1. Use a dialog /pop-up on your button click like JOptionPane.
2. If you want to open a JFrame on button click, making a HOME button on the newly created/opened JFrame and linking that button to main JFrame might be a good option.Closing the newly created JFrame will display the originally created JFrame anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dialog (`JDialog` class) instead and make it modal.
Here is some help on how to do this:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Regards,